# R 64-bit shiny ERROR: invalid 'nchars' argument

Tags: r, windows, shiny, 64-bit

I am currently moving a (localhost) shiny App from a windows 32-bit to windows 64-bit . Google didn't managed to answer my problem :( so I'm asking the community !
This App worked fine on 32 bits, I had to re-install R, all Packages, Java on the 64-bit machine (each in the 64-bit mode). My app has the following file architecture :

- a gloabl.R file where I load libraries
- a server.R
- List item
- a ui.R
- another file which format data to be sent d3/nvd3
- a JS file to display a linechart.

the error I have is the following :

> Warning in file(con, "rb") :   
> file("") only supports open = "w+" and
>   open = "w+b": using the former 
> Warning: Error in readChar: invalid
>   'nchars' argument 
> Stack trace (innermost first):
>       
> 1: runApp Error : invalid 'nchars' argument

When I'm running code without shiny, all works fine, all is precessed and results are good.

Does anyone has ever been facing to this ?

If you need anything just ask I will be more specific. I am not giving you the code, he is a little tricky and is in multiple files... And I think it is specific to my new environement.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling solely the shiny-package fixed the problem for me. I am using R-studio, and did the operation through the Packages window (deleted and reinstalled).